# Are the means of the two data sets statistically different?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

A 95% confidence interval for the difference of means for two data sets  A and B was constructed. The confidence interval is (-2.1,.5). Are the means of the two data sets statistically different?

I am kind of confused about this question.

Comment: Sorry I mean confidence interval for the difference of means for two data sets was constructed.

Comment: So if it is observed that $a-b\in(-2.1,0.5)$, what can you say about the hypothesis $a-b\ne 0$?

Comment: Then a-b does not equal zero if false.